# Is there any functionality in Corda Quickstart's Notary node?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Good day!

Just deployed 3 Party-nodes and one Notary node, as described [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#id1). I see that the Notary node is up.

The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to work with Notary. I created some IOUs and I assume that these IOUs should be verified somehow in the Notary or am I wrong?

I also see that samples\cordapp-example\kotlin-source\src\main\kotlin\com\example\api\ExampleApi.kt contains only the API for Party nodes.

So the question is "Does Notary server from CORDA Quickstart provides any API for verifying the IOUs?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the notary is validating or non-validating.

If the notary is validating, it will verify any transactions it receives as part of `FinalityFlow`. This happens automatically by running the contracts, and requires no intervention from the operator of the notary node.

If the notary is non-validating, it will not see the full transaction, nor will it verify it.

Note also that notaries are only sent transactions that have input states and/or timestamps.

Comment: Joel. thank you for your answer! 
As I see, in samples\cordapp-example\kotlin-source\build\nodes\Notary\node.conf file my Notary is non-validating (validating=false).
However, anyway, whether Notary is validation or not, there is no need in operator approving transactions, so the Notary doesn't have any API, am I right?

Comment: Right, the notary does it automatically if you use the standard notary flows.